# create custom exception triggering when length of commnd line argument is less than 2 in JAVA

Tags: java

**create custom exception triggering when length of command line argument is less than 2 in java.**Use custom exception.The input should be from command prompt.

Comment: a) do you know what an exception is?  b) Do you know how to extend a class  c) Do you know how to throw an exception

Comment: yes i know how it do it

Comment: You have tried anything ? Then better to the show the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when the user does not enter correct number the arguments, a **Usage Message** is printed.

```
if(args.length < 2){
     System.out.println("Usage: java abc xyz");
}
```

You can throw an exception there using the throw keyword. But it serves no purpose, since the program is running on command line.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And then throw the exception after checking the number of argument. It will print the exception with the usage message.

```
if(args.length < 2){
    throw new MyException("Usage: java abc xyz");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the steps, not code:

1) create class that extends [Exception class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

```
 class InputNotValidException extends Exception
 {
    public InputNotValidException()
    {
        super();
    }
    public InputNotValidException(String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }

    ....
    .....
 }
```

2)Now create class that has `main()` which accepts input and throws exception

```
 class ExceptionDemo
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //check args length 
        if(args.length < 2)
          throw new InputNotValidException("Arguments not valid"); 
        else
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
 }
```

**Related links**

1. [What is exception?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)
2. [exception tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)
3. [How to throw custom exception example1](http://www.java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/)
4. [How to throw custom exception example2](http://www.javatpoint.com/custom-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom exception class by either extending the `Exception` class for a checked exception or extending the `RuntimeException` class for an unchecked exception.